# Is there any way to change the image color?

Tags: css

Is there any way to change the color of an `img` (not background) using css?

I mean there is an image and on hover I want to say darken it, best way to do it? And yes is it possible without using opacity?

Comment: place div over it and use opactity on that div?

Comment: Yes...using the `filter` properties...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: no, it is impossible

Comment: @Begueradj No...it's not - see above

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you, it is something totally new to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS filters, example:

Change saturation:

```
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
```

or change the brightness:

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(.5);
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/m9sjdbx6/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/m9sjdbx6/4/

```
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-hAOQ_DrZM1E/Ub6s63_iqxI/AAAAAAAC9hc/2mfBJjeQNos/s1600/Blind+Chess-Board.jpg"></img>
```

Saturation (color):

```
img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(270deg);

}
```

Brightness:

```
img:hover {
-webkit-filter: brightness(0.2);


}
```

Comment: You should also mention the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @chipChocolate.py thanks for commenting, yes above script will work on webkit based browsers

Answer (score 3):

You could use CSS3 filters, like this:

```
img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(.5);
  filter: brightness(.5);
}
```

For more compatibility infos - [CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Comment: Let the unprefixed version come last :)

Comment: I thought he wanted to darken it? Changing the brightness darkens the image ^^

Comment: @pimmey yes you are right OP wanted to change the brightness but the word color in the question was misleading :-)